# Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a spring boot app (`2.3.0.M2`) running on aws. While accessing it from local react app running on `localhost:3000`, I was getting following error:

```
Access to XMLRequest at aws-url from origin localhost:3000 has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present on the request resource.
```

I tried to solve it by adding the CORS policy to the spring boot app, by adding a `WebConfig` as below:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**");
  }
}
```

And now getting `Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json] after cors policy updated`. `Using 'application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json', given [*/*] and supported [application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json, application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json]`.

I have also tried specifically defining the core policies for content-type(as application/json). And tried removing the `produces=content-type` from controller, which is not a great idea but it doesn't work.

It goes to the controller, and fails at the return statement. This is how the controller looks:

```java
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

@RestController
public class SomeController {

  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  @GetMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public Object get(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    return service.get(id);
  }
}
```

What am I missing? any captain to rescue?

Comment: Could you add the request from your browser also in the question ? Have you tried specifying `configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));` in cors configuratison ?

Comment: The request is as simple as `localhost:8080/1`, it is same from postman and from browser. About origin, the error is not about origin, `/**` means allowing all origins. By the way I tried adding origin but still the same error.

Comment: are you using Spring Security ?

Comment: no, not using spring security.

Comment: @AnilBhaskar When you provide the cors configuration try configuring it with all the necessary parameters like allowed origin, allowed methods etc as these headers needs to be present in the pre flight check response in order for the request to be a success. In your case you just provided the cors mapping as `/**` which mean cors conf will be applied on all url mappings. You still need to specify the allowed origins as `* ` etc

Comment: I have the same problem so it would be helpful to know if the OP has solved the problem and how. It could really help me. My post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65050073/bad-request-from-saving-structured-json-object)